# iOS Passbook: how to use ruby to generate signature for pass

Tags: ios, ruby, openssl, passbook

I used to do this in shell:

```
openssl smime -binary -sign -certfile WWDR.pem -signer passcertificate.pem -inkey passkey.pem -in manifest.json -out signature -outform DER -passin pass:12345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command-line tool for OpenSSL just makes use of the OpenSSL library. As it is written in C, you can use it natively in your iOS project. It isn't included with iOS, but you can download the source code from [here](http://www.openssl.org/source/) and compile it yourself, as it is open source.

Using the library natively will be much faster, and much more reliable.

Comment: I am not sure how this solves the poster's question. Signing passes from within an app requires embedding the private key for the Pass Type ID certificate within the app bundle.  Apple recommends that passes be signed on a server.  Ruby has an OpenSSL library with a [PKCS7 class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS7.html) that should be capable of replicating the shell command.

Comment: The asker gave an example of the OpenSSL command line tool. The command line tool is just a wrapper for the OpenSSL library. Anything he does through the command line tool can be done directly through the library. His question was not very well formatted, and did not explicitly specify Ruby. Instead, he gave a shell command. My question perfectly involves the poster's question.

Comment: Yeah, I guess "how to use ruby to generate signature for pass" is a pretty unclear question title.